# Data Objects from $.ajax with json are shallow

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, ecmascript-6

I've got a JSON looking like this (design might be wrong)

```
{
  "Supermarkt": {
    "name": "Supermarkt",
    "translations": {
      "trolley": "Einkaufswagen",
      "vegetables": "Gemüse",
      "cocoa": "Kakao",
      "chocolate": "Schokolade"
    },
    "pronunciations": []
  },
  "Script1336Kidee": {
    "name": "Script1336Kidee",
    "translations": {
      "Trojaner": "RAT",
      "Laufzeit-Packer": "Magie",
      "PHP": "Der letzte Dreck",
      "JavaScript": "Wild-West"
    },
    "pronunciations": []
  }
}
```

Which I get with a ajax call (already JSON-decoded through dataType: "json" $.ajax option):

```
let lessonCall = $.ajax("https://www2.htw-dresden.de/~s70357/vokabel.php/",{dataType: "json"});
lessonCall.fail((jqXHR, status, error) => {
    console.log(status);
    console.log(error);
});
lessonCall.done((data,status) => {
    console.log(status);
    console.log(data);
    for (let lesson in data){
        console.log(lesson);
        console.log(lesson.name);
    }
});
```

**Problem** is `lesson.name` is undefined although `console.log(data);` show the healthy data Object with the healthy subsub-Objects, but lesson seems to be just a string-like thing.

How can I iterate through my `"name"`s?!

Comment: `lesson` is the property name not the value, per [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: @James So how can I fix it?

Comment: How do you get a property value from an object, having the property name in a variable?  obj[propertyName].

Comment: Yeah, I was not realizing that I'm operating at that "array-level" I was trying `lesson["name"]` but it never occurred to that for in just get's me the indexes. Javascript beginner, sorry, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (let i in data){
    let lesson = data[i];
    console.log(lesson);
    console.log(lesson.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling `let jsonData = JSON.parse(data)` before your `for` loop?

Would you be able to modify the json format? If so, you could turn it into an array:

```
[   
  {
    "name": "Supermarkt",
    "translations": {
      "trolley": "Einkaufswagen",
      "vegetables": "Gemüse",
      "cocoa": "Kakao",
      "chocolate": "Schokolade"
    },
    "pronunciations": []   
  },   
  {
    "name": "Script1336Kidee",
    "translations": {
      "Trojaner": "RAT",
      "Laufzeit-Packer": "Magie",
      "PHP": "Der letzte Dreck",
      "JavaScript": "Wild-West"
    },
    "pronunciations": []   
  } 
]
```

Comment: Yes, then I get parse erros as expected since it's already parsed by $.ajax : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.lessonCall.done (vokabeltrainer.js:31)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous>

Comment: What does the `console.log(lesson);` show?

Comment: Just `Supermarkt` and `Script1336Kidee` (just the property name not the value, as James pointed out) . Michał Perłakowski s Answer worked, I guess it's in one more array, I don't get that whole javascript "type system" yet.
But thx for trying!

Comment: Cool. No problem! I also posted another json format you could try if you have the access to modify it since you mentioned "(design might be wrong)"

Comment: @Eriv B Funny, I had it in this format, but IIRC that gives you parse errors, since it's not legal json. (That whole thing is top level)